# CSS is not working after installation in Magento 2

Tags: css, ubuntu, magento2

I have Installed Magento 2.

Everything completed successfully but the CSS is not loading.

I tried these commands

```
php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: You should also undo the settings provided to you in the accepted answer. It is completely unsafe.

Comment: I was working on my local server and looking for an answer from more than 2 days than i posted here and it worked for me i saw the comments who are blaming the guy who answered , no one gave the answered instead of this you are down voting an answer which helped me even i know that 777 is not safe but was important for me that time to have an answer. So i request better to provide an answer rather than pointing someone who is helping others.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're on your local machine or not - Stack Overflow's purpose is to provide a repository of questions and answers for the community at large. So when an answer is as dangerous as the answer you accepted it needs to be highlighted as such, for the community. This is not, in any way, about slinging mud at anyone.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You should Provide Some permissions

run this command

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod -R 777 {} \; 
&& sudo find . -type f -exec chmod -R 777  {} \; 
&& sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: I provided permission 
chmod -R 777 magentoDir

Comment: Don't do this way it is not at all a good practice try the command i answered

Comment: But 777 is not at all safe, and will leave you vunerable to attacks. Please look at recommended user creation and related permissions http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html and http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: but if we give 777 to pub/static and var directory only, is that okay? because i think these directories only save cache and static content.

Answer (score 1):

Please, before doing anything go to **magento2 basedir** and do:

```
nano vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/DriverInterface.php
```

and change

```
const WRITEABLE_DIRECTORY_MODE = 0770;
```

from 0770 to **0775**

and

```
const WRITEABLE_FILE_MODE = 0660;
```

from 0660 to **0644**

*The above set 0775 for folders and 0644 for files on generated/cached entities*

Then change whole magento2 filesystem to the same permissions

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

**Important**,
you should execute bin/magento as a common user, and not as root. So if you are in bin/ folder you may use for example:

```
sudo -u youasuser php -d memory_limit=512M magento setup:upgrade
```

You need memory_limit=512 as some callings like *setup:di:compile* needs more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Please check `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your web server.

Comment: Nginx newbie here: how do I check this?

Comment: @ScottAnderson , this tip is for Apache server only. I don't know nginx, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

1. First create a magento_user: `adduser <username>` and give user a password `passwd <username>` (May have to use sudo, if not already root)
2. Find your web server group: `ps aux | grep apache` Typically `www-data`
3. Add new user to this group: `usermod -g www-data <username>`
4. `groups <username>` should show the groups that username belongs to.
5. Restart webserver, so permissions can take effect `service apache2 restart`
6. Set ownerships of files in Magento root. `chown -R :<your web server group name> .`
7. Finally set permissions `find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento`

Reference: [Set file system ownership and permissions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html) and [Create the Magento file system owner](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html)