# Site is not working after 777 permission to var folder in Magento2

Tags: error-handling, permissions, reset, magento2

Hi I need to install an extension in Magento 2 and it was throwing error for writable permission in var folder.

> I have given 777 permission recursively
>
> and after that the site is not working .

Can you please suggest me how can I reset the permissions to the Magento2 site?

Comment: Have you created a magento user? And this user is in group that owns the files? Please this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301066/css-not-working-after-installation-in-magento-2/36405944#36405944

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 permissions are described [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html), and '777' is too much. I suppose, you need to clean cached and generated files that can be broken after the installation of your extension was failed:

```
$ ./bin/magento cache:clean
```

switch to the development mode, see the errors in logs (`./var/log/`) then switch back to production mode:

```
$ ./bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
$ ./bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```